# the find Method returning empty array even though there is a record present in the database using typeORM in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

So this is my Problem, i created a Nestjs API with Typeorm.

I created a many To One relation :

```
  @ManyToOne(() => DoctorEntity, (doctor) => doctor.consultation, {
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  })
  doctor: DoctorEntity;
```

and i was able to create consultations and successfully save in database ::

[image: Image in DataBase]

as you can see above the relation is being saved in the database.

So My Problem is When i try to Fetch all Consultation thats that have relation to a doctor it returning an empty screen.

```
 const user = await this.doctorRepo.findOne({
        where: {
          id: req['user'],
        },
      });

      if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('user Not found');

      const consultation = await this.consultationRepo.find({
        where: {
          doctor: user as FindOptionsWhere<DoctorEntity>,
        },

        relations: ['patient', 'patient.history', 'patient.prescriptions'],
      });

      return {
        status: 'success',
        message: 'Fetched SuccessFully',
        data: consultation,
      };
```

Ive Tried Checking the Entity for both consultation and Doctors Everything looks fine but its still not fetching

Comment: What does your `consultation` entity look like? What happens if you toss an ` eager:true` into either the `consultation` or `doctor` relation options?

Comment: @ManyToOne(() => DoctorEntity, (doctor) => doctor.consultation, {
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  })
  doctor: DoctorEntity; .... this is the consultation entity relation @Damon